How to get access from a clientside job on the server to process further?
First of all, I am not sure, if i understand the Hangfire thing correctly. My understanding is, put something in the Hangfire DB from the clientside, meanwhile the server is running and monitoring. When something is coming in from the client (--> an entry in the hangfire db) us this and - this is where my problem is appearing - do some logic on the server side.
So I have a Job on the client side in an Console Application:
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue("download-model", () => CreateModel(new DataModel()));

//..
//..

public static string CreateModel(DataModel model)
{
    model.Application = "FileApp";
    model.Filename = "TestFileName.pdf";
    model.Weburi = @"https://example.com/";
    model.RegId = "abcd";
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
}

When I ran the Program it gets into the Queue `ID: 51 Status: Enqueued Job: Program.CreateModel.
What I want to achieve is, that the server gets triggered and uses the data from CreateModel to download a file. So that the server looks up in the Hangfire database: Oh, CreateModel is in the Database, take it and do some logic on the serverside for example calling ModelFileDownload with the given parameters.
I don't know how to achieve this. The only thing i get from the hangfire server dashboard is:
Job done.

//Job ID: #50
Program.CreateModel(FromJson<DataModel>("{}"));

Status Succeeded
Result: "{\"Application\":\"FileApp\",\"Filename\": ....}"

But I don't know how to access this to put it in a serverside logic, when the client side is fired.
-------------- UPDATE ------------
So to break it down, this is what I think hangfire is doing when I run it:

Client: var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue("download-model", () => CreateModel(new DataModel()));
Client is writing it into the Hangfire DB via BackgroundJob.Enqueue
Server: The server is waiting for an download-model entry, grabs it and is using the datamodel to build the URL and download it - so on the server i run:
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("download-model", () => DownloadFile(null), Cron.Minutely);
Server: For my understanding it is calling the DownloadFile (one more problem: I don't know how to access the arguments, so here I wrote null in it and worked with a dummy, here is the logic:

    public static Task DownloadFile(PerformContext context)
    {
        var jobId = context.BackgroundJob.Id;
        Console.WriteLine(jobId);
    
        string url = "www.example.com/"; 
        string documentId = context.RegId; //... had dummy here instead
        
        Uri url = new System.Uri(url + documentId);
    
        var certificate = GetCertificate();
    
        if (certificate != null)
        {
           //...
           DownloadServiceClient(url, certificate);
           //...
        }
        //...
    
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

I am really not sure if I am missunderstanding Hangfire.

can you share with us the logic for download ? I think that you misunderstood the hangfire logic - you are close - but not there yet.

ty @J.Memisevic I added the code. I am worried and not sure if I understand the concept Hangfire correctly. I hope you can help me.

Ok, first that is not how Hangfire works.
What Hangfire does when you do the Enqueue is saves job definition to its own database then Hanfire server picks up that job loads it using assembly scanning and activates you method.
So in your example it just desearializes the DataModel and returns Json.
So for your method to work as expected - download a document in the job you should just create a job like this:
public class DownloadJob
{
  public Task Download(DataModel model)
  {     
        Uri url = new System.Uri(model.Weburi + model.DocumentId);
    
        var certificate = GetCertificate();
    
        if (certificate != null)
        {
           //...
           DownloadServiceClient(url, certificate);
           //...
        }
        //...
    
        return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
}

So you would enqueue it like this:
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<DownloadJob>( job=> job.Download(model));

Or if you wanna combine it with Recuring Job , then I would save download model to database(via repository) - in its own table for example [dbo].[DownloadModel]. Inside the recuring job I would have a method to fetch model from database (via repository) and download data, update the model that for that model data has been downloaded.

Ok, getting closer, ty. But I have the model on the Client application (I thought BackgroundJob.Enqueue is on the client. And the Download(model) is on the server side. So I have the client side with the argugemnts, writing into the HF Database and the server is using the arguments to access Download(model).

Well in order to make it work like this they would have to have a shared lib with download job. If you don't want to share code. You would have to just put download model to database and have recuring job that would read that data from database and  execute download.

What are you missing in the update, added above the Client/Server things? I can give it to you. :) Your answer class DownloadJob is on the client side and with Enqueue it is in the DB. How can I use the model on server, with which Hangfire Method? Unfortunately I have to use hangfire. To simplify it, forget the model and I just give a string downloadUrl argument from the client side to the database via Enqueue. Then my only problem is: With which command I can retrieve the url and use it serverside? How can I get the argument to the server. By using AddOrUpdate? Thank you so much.
